# Calling a IValidateObject Validate method from client Side MVC3

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I am very new to MVC and I am using MVC 3 in our Project..

I implemented Model level validation using IValidateObject..and I created the Validate method with some validation logic on my model...

I saw some other interface called Iclientvalidatable for calling validation methods from jquery validation(client side)..

Now I am trying to call the Validate method from client side...Is it possible??

Do I need to implement Iclientvalidatable interface on same model and needs to write the same logic in this method also??

Or Can I directly access the validate method from IClietnValidatable method??

My goal is accessing the validate method logic from client side..If its not possible to do..then i need to write same logic on client side also...

Please help me..thanks..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IValidatableObject in MVC3 - client side validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748703/ivalidatableobject-in-mvc3-client-side-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot link class level validators to client side validation.

See [IValidatableObject in MVC3 - client side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748703/ivalidatableobject-in-mvc3-client-side-validation/4826678#4826678)

Comment: ok. I got it. I go with normal Jquery validation and its very simple to implement..Thanks for your support....

Answer (score 1):

If you want custom client side validation you need to [implement the `IClientValidatable` interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833280/asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-custom-client-validation/4833648#4833648) but the actual validation logic should be done using javascript. And here's [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784943/asp-net-mvc-3-client-side-validation-with-parameters/4784986#4784986).

Comment: this one works fine if we want to compare two fields...i want to do a group validation like "if any one of them is required"..and this field is in conjunction with those two date fields..how can i handle this kind of scenarios..i have already did the logic on model level..but how to use that code for Iclientvalidatable interface...thanks for your help..

Comment: @Sunny43, please provide a specific example of what you are trying to achieve.